# How To Append TR on DataTable which Inherit the first row's class?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I am using the code below to dynamically add a new row. My problem is if I re-adjust the window, only the first fixed row turns into a collapsible one. The dynamically added row doesn't inherit the class of the first fixed row.

```
<script>
var x = 1;  
function addContainer1(){
var max_fields_limit      = 10; 

$('.myApe').append('<tr role="row" class="even">'+
'<td><input type="text" name="TEU[]" id="TEU" class="form-control"></td> '+
'<td><div class="row"><input type="text" name="CBM[]" id="CBM" class="form-control">'+
'<button class="remove_field" onclick="removeContainer()">-</button>        </div></td>'+
'</tr>');           
x++;            
$('.myApe').on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
    e.preventDefault(); $(this).closest('tr').remove(); x--;
})
}
```

[image]

```
<table id="example14" class="table table-striped table-sm">
<thead>

<tr>
<th>Container No</th>
 <th>CBM</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody class="myApe">
          
<tr>
<td>
<input type="text" name="TEU[]" id="TEU" class="form-control" placeholder="Container Number"  required> 
</td>

<td>
<div class="row">
<input type="text" name="CBM[]" id="CBM" class="form-control" placeholder="CBM"  required style="width:80%">
<button type="button"  class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" onclick="addContainer1()">+</button>
</div>
</td>
</tr>                   
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The row isn't going to inherit a class from a sibling element.  What does your CSS/HTML look like and what are you expecting?

Comment: How can I just add a row that is collapsible by default? so that it adjust to the size of the screen.

Comment: Where is your html ?

Comment: i just added the html part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of adding the new data row to the DOM using `$('.myApe').append()`, you need to add the row to the DataTable, so that DataTables knows the new row exists - and can handle it in the correct way.

You can use the [`row().data()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().data()) API call to do this.

The following runnable example uses a string of HTML to represent the new row. Click on the "add new row" button to add a 4th row to the table:

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {

    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
      responsive: true,
      columnDefs: [
        { responsivePriority: 1, targets: -2 }
      ]
    } );

    let newRow = "<tr><td>4</td><td>Donna Snider</td><td>Customer Support</td><td>New York</td><td>27</td><td>2011/01/25</td><td>$112,000</td></tr>";

    $( "button" ).on( "click", function() {
      table.row.add( $(newRow) ).draw();
      $( "button" ).off(); // this demo only adds one row
    });

  } );
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Demo</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://datatables.net/media/css/site-examples.css">

  <!-- responsive plug-in -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.6/css/responsive.dataTables.css"/>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.6/js/dataTables.responsive.js"></script>
  
</head>

<body>

<div style="margin: 20px;">

    <button type="button">Add New Row</button> 

    <br><br>

    <table id="example" class="display dataTable nowrap cell-border" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start Date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2009/01/12</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2012/03/29</td>
                <td>$433,060</td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

You don't have to provide a DOM `<tr>` row in the `row().data()` function. You can also use JavaScript arrays and objects (depending on how the original data was provided to the table).

---

**Update**

The follow-up question is:

> *how to delete a row if, for example, I added too many rows?*

To delete a row from a DataTable you can use the [`row().remove()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().remove()) API function. For this you need to identify which row you want to remove.

There are various ways to do this.

One common way is to add a button into each row (there are various SO questions and answers covering this) and then use the button's click event to locate the parent `<tr>` containing the button.

Feel free to ask a new question if you get stuck with any specific step, but I think it should be OK to implement this, using the examples in the link and with help from existing SO questions.

Comment: How can I add multiple rows?       $( "button" ).off(); // this demo only adds one row

Comment: was able to make it work! Thanks! my only question now is how to delete row if say for example i added to much rows.

Comment: I added some notes to the answer for row deletion.

Comment: thank you! I was able to delete rows by adding buttons at the end of it. right now, when add row. it can add a row, i can delete the row. but when i click add row, it adds the deleted row plus a new row. anyway i can have a counter or something that it always add just a row? where in the code can i add incremental variable?

Comment: I think  this is difficult to answer with any confidence, without seeing the code to accompany your description of the issue - I really do recommend a new question for that. (It sounds like you may want to use the internally assigned DataTables row ID, or something like that. Maybe...).